# Java script access ASP.net MVC ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am quite new in ASP.net MVC model and having a bit problem here (absolutely newbie).

My problem is i cannot access the ViewData via client-side java script to render a table using the data from my server side.

I having a main menu at the top consist of several link button, after the user click on it, it will change the sub menu on the right side. The menu item is dynamic where is queue from my server database.

any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`ViewData["something"]` contains some server side object which cannot be used directly by javascript unless some simple type such as integer, string, ... You could JSON serialize it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var menuList = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewData["MenuList"]) %>;
    // TODO: use the menuList javascript variable
</script>
```

Also I would recommend you using strongly typed views with view models instead of the `ViewData` hashtable.